# Dredd - Getting error when parsing swagger file 'API description parser warning in'

Tags: swagger, dredd

I've recently upgraded Dredd from version 4.8 to 8+, and started getting the dozens of theses errors when Dredd attempts to parse the Swagger and generate the transaction request body. Each error is about a different row in the swagger file.

```
warn: API description parser warning in /builds/swagger.yaml:64 (from line 64 column 8 to line 66 column 6): Unable to generate application/json; charset=utf-8 example message body out of JSON Schema
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to share the swagger file.
But Dredd does manage to generate the request headers just fine.

This is the general settings of the swagger file:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '3'
  title: 'API'
schemes:
- 'http'
consumes:
- application/json; charset=utf-8
produces:
- application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The swagger file did not change between Dredd version upgrades.
Please advise on what can be the cause.

Comment: Hi, could you share the Swagger document with us at support@apiary.io and we can take a look into what is causing this error with your document

Comment: sure, what should I send in subject? should I send it with the error description as written here?

Comment: @kylef, I've sent an email